# jQuery: appendTo either elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there a good way to `.appendTo` either one element or the either depending on if it exists in the DOM?

So for example ideally I would like to do

**ideal method 1:**

```
.appendTo($('#div1') || $('#div2'));
```

**not so good method 2:**

```
var div1 = $('#div1'),
    div2 = $('#div2'),
    e = div1;

if (!div1.length) e = div2;

.appendTo(e);
```

Of course I can't do the first option because $() always returns an object so it will evaluate to true `alert($ || 'a');` will always return the jQuery object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they're in order just use [`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/), like this:

```
.appendTo($("#div1, #div2").first());
```

Whichever order they occur in the DOM in, just use [`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) or [`.last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/) to select from the direction you want.  Also `.appendTo()` just gets swapped around, it'd be better to do this:

```
$("#div1, #div2").first().append(element);
```

Comment: thanks that's a good way of doing it! would `.eq()` work in the same way?

Comment: @Gary - Yup, they're just convenience functions, `.first()` is `.eq(0)` and `.last()` is just `.eq(-1)` behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
  ($("#div1").get(0) || $("#div2").get(0)).appendTo(..)
```

Assuming at least one of them exists.

Comment: this is good too, didn't know about `.get` thanks for this :)

Answer (score 0):

why not just set a class on the  the divs. this way if one of the divs is present it will always work.

Comment: In some cases both divs can be present so I don't want it appending twice